# How to re-boot liftweb?

Tags: scala, lift

I have my Boot.scala with boot method in it where i do my setup. 
At the end, I make the call to LiftRules.statelessDispatchTable and append an new instance of my class that extends the RestHelper, which has the serve block.

At some point, I get a signal and need to change this class, so i need to make another call into the statelessDispatchTable to remove the original one and add a new one.

What's a good way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I AM GOING TO UPDATE THE QUESTION WITH THE ANSWER I GOT FROM DAVID POLLAK:

You can't. Once your app is started, there's no way to change LiftRules.

However, the stuff you're adding to statelessDispatchTable is a PartialFunction[Req, Box[LiftResponse]] so you can write a PartialFunction that looks like:

```
object RestThing1 extends RestHelper { .... }

object RestThing2 extends RestHelper {....}

object MyDynamicRestThing extends PartialFunction[Req, Box[LiftResponse]] {
  def isDefinedAt(in: Req): Boolean = if (testCondition) RestThing1.isDefinedAt(in) else RestThing2.isDefinedAt(in)
  def apply(in: Req): Box[LiftRequest] = if (testCondition) RestThing1.apply(in) else RestThing2.apply(in)
}

LiftRules.statelessDispatchTable.append(MyDynamicRestThing)
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `LiftRules.statelessDispatchTable.prepend` to shadow your original RestHelper with new one?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second-level dispatch...e.g., an object that receives the requests, then according to some other logic proxies the requests on to the real handler. Then you don't have to mess with the top-level dispatch table at all.

Would really make sense to do this if what you are needing to do is toggle it based on a signal (e.g. it will revert back at some point), or if there is additional logic that would benefit from being in a proper abstraction.